# How to find element with attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="item" data-value="100">Something</div>
```

Now, I am using the following to find this element:

```
$( "div[data-value=value]")
```

Where `value` is `"100"`. However, I don't think jquery sees the `value` as javascript object - I think it takes it as it is. How can I fix this?

Comment: `$( "div[data-value=" + value + "]") `

Answer (score 3):

Using filter

```
var $item = $('.item').filter(function(){
   return $(this).data('value') == 100;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "div[data-value=" + value + "]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use concatenation

```
var value = 100;
$( "div[data-value='"+value+"']");
```